# What's the max DT without wearing armor in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm roleplaying now with a character who wears no armor, only fancy suits.

I could use a combination of perks and skills (so far I'm planning on getting the implant and the toughness perk), but is there anything else I should get, and how much DT will it provide?

Comment: Is Power Armor a "fancy suit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list does not account for [damage resistance](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance), only [damage threshold](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Threshold)

Perks:
Toughness (2 ranks) +3DT per rank
Stonewall +5DT against melee and unarmed
Nerd Rage! +15DT when health is less than 20%
Hit the Deck! +25DT against explosives
Whiskey Rose +2DT when drinking whiskey

Consumables:
Whiskey (with Whiskey Rose) +2DT (4min*)
Datura hide (Honest hearts DLC) +1DT (1 min)

Clothing:
Dr. Mobius' Scrubs (Old World Blues DLC) +6DT
Bounty Hunter duster +6DT

Based off of this, the absolute highest DT you can have is 55DT;
2 ranks of Toughness, bonus DT from Nerd Rage!, having recently consumed whisky and Datura hide +3DT, wearing either of the apparel listed for 6DT and fighting an enemy who uses explosives for a bonus 25DT

*Whisky rose effect length is not explicitly listed, but other Whiskey effects last for 4 minutes, this one probably does too.

Comment: Don't you mean - in this ideal situation - it would be ((2x3)+15+3+6+25=) 55DT?

Comment: You are correct. I don't know where I messed up my math.